# How to open a list of music files with batch for being played by default music player one after the other?

Tags: windows, batch-file, mp3

My grandma asked me for help to get her music easily started. I decided to make a small batch script that opens all files in her music folders.

The script should simulate pressing <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and then right click to open. This way the system default music player automatically starts all these songs as a playlist.

Has anyone an idea how all files in a folder can be played by the music playing program?

I have not really scripted much with batch. It was very complicated to get this to work what I have done so far. So, sorry in advance.

Here is my partly working code. The problem is that it only starts the first audio file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd "path\to\her\music"

set "fileList="

for %%a in ("*.mp3") do (
    set "filename=%%~nxa"
    set "extension=!filename:~-3!"
    if /i "!extension!"=="mp3" (
        echo Marking file: "%%a"
        attrib +R "%%a"
        set "fileList=!fileList! "%%a""
    )
)

echo done.
timeout 1 > NUL

::echo Opening files: %fileList%
start "" %fileList%

pause
```

I also tried to replace the command line `start "" %fileList%` with this. The problem was that now every file gets started separately, so that the system music player opens the next track separately over and over again.

```
for %%a in ("*.mp3") do (
    set "filename=%%~nxa"
    set "extension=!filename:~-3!"
    if /i "!extension!"=="mp3" (
        start "" "%%a"
    )
)
```

Comment: The extension is `.mp3` not `mp3`!

Comment: @Compo - True, but `!extension!` is set to the last three characters. It's unnecessary, but still fine.